# confusion comparing structures

Tags: c, types, structure

the question is to calculate the average of each student separately and then show the id and the average of rank one student. how to compare members of structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct student
{
    int id;
    float math,physics;
    float av;
}std;

int main()
{
int i;
std p[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    printf("enter student(%d) id: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&p[i].id);
    printf("grade of math over 100: ");
    scanf("%f",&p[i].math);
    printf("grade of physics over 100: ");
    scanf("%f",&p[i].physics);
    printf("average=%.3f\n\n",(p[i].math+p[i].physics)/2);
    }

}
```

Comment: You never set the member `av`. Once you set it, you can compare easily with something like `if (p[2].av > p[3].av) printf("student 2 has greater average then student 3\n");`

Comment: probably you also want `p[i].av = (p[i].math+p[i].physics)/2;` ? Also check your `scanf` return 1 to know if a valid input was given, then check the value is between 0 (probably) and 100

Comment: what do you mean by "*how to compare members of structure*" ? Do you want to find the student having the higher av ?

Comment: (p[2].av > p[3].av) this can be generalized to p[i].av > p[i+1].av ?

Comment: as long as you use it in a loop then yes. But you have to declare i somewhere such that the generalization can work.

Answer (score 0):

To compare on element with another you would take either 
`p[index]->av {comparaision} p[index]->av`

Example `p[0]->av > p[1]->av`

Don't forget `printf("average=%.3f\n\n",(p[i].math+p[i].physics)/2);` will print you the result of av but will not save it in p. Save it in p[index].av to be able to do comparaisons.

Then afterward just do a loop where you compare each of them and save their id in an array. The array should be based on a decreasing average with the matching id. Then  just print the array and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct studentd
{   int id;
    float math,physics;
    float av;
} std;

int main()
{
    int i,a;
    std p[5];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("student(%d) id: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&p[i].id);
        printf("grade of math over 100: ");
        scanf("%f",&p[i].math);
        printf("grade of physics over 100: ");
        scanf("%f",&p[i].physics);
        printf("average=%.3f\n\n",p[i].av=(p[i].math+p[i].physics)/2);
    }
    int max=p[0].av;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(p[i].av<=p[i+1].av)
        {
            max=p[i].av;

        }
    }

    printf("the highest average is for student: %d ",p[i].id);
    return 0;
}


/*END*/
```

/*now this is the updated code my problem is how to link the id of student to the max to show the id of student whi got the highest mark*/

Answer (score 0):

Well one of two things,
Either add an integer to track the index of the structure containing the max,

Or instead of 
max =p[i].avg
Use max = p[i]
Of  course let max be a struct not float or int